# Qt- Add custom font from resource

Tags: c++, qt, fonts

I added this font to resource: *BYekan.ttf*
I want to use this font in my application. I've tried this :

```
    QFont font(":/images/font/BYekan.ttf");
    nLabel->setFont(font);
    nLabel->setText(tr("This is for test"));
    layout->addWidget(nLabel);
```

But, I guess it's not working. How to use it?

Edit:
After reading [this question](http://www.qtforum.org/article/25367/embedding-custom-fonts.html) , I've tried again :

```
int fontID(-1);
bool fontWarningShown(false);
QFile res(":/images/font/Yekan.ttf");
if (res.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) == false) {
    if (fontWarningShown == false) {
        QMessageBox::warning(0, "Application", (QString)"Impossible d'ouvrir la police " + QChar(0x00AB) + " DejaVu Serif " + QChar(0x00BB) + ".");
        fontWarningShown = true;
    }
}else {
    fontID = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFontFromData(res.readAll());
    if (fontID == -1 && fontWarningShown == false) {
        QMessageBox::warning(0, "Application", (QString)"Impossible d'ouvrir la police " + QChar(0x00AB) + " DejaVu Serif " + QChar(0x00BB) + ".");
        fontWarningShown = true;

    }
    else
        nLabel->setFont(QFont(":/images/font/Yekan.ttf", 10));
}
```

I compare this font and other font, but there isn't any different on Qt. why?

Comment: Try 
QFont font(":/images/font/BYekan.ttf");
nLabel->setFont(font);

Comment: I tried it , but still it's not working

Answer (score 57):

```
int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/monospace.ttf");
QString family = QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).at(0);
QFont monospace(family);
```

Comment: How to use it ? 
nLabel->setFont(monospace(family));

error: no match for call to '(QFont) (QString&)'

Comment: No, Like this.
nLabel->setFont(monospace);

Comment: id is -1, if the font cannot be loaded

Comment: I noticed that loading an application which used just a system installed fonts very faster than an application which used embedded fonts. Also I tried to use non-compressed font outside qrc file. but same result.

Comment: In my case, `QFile::exists` returns `true` but `QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont` returns `-1`. What could cause this?

Comment: In my case, the file name was spelled with a different capitalization, and that's why it returned -1.

Answer (score 5):

In QML you can

```
FontLoader { id: font; source: "/fonts/font.otf" }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as reported in the original question. The above presented solution (answer beginning with the line "int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont....) however did not work, as can be also seen in the comments above. addApplicationFont returned -1.

The reason is, that there is a leading ':' in the string for the call of the function addApplicationFont. I removed this. Now it works for me (testet with Qt 5.5.1 and Qt 4.8.6 on Linux) and returns 0.  On Windows it might be necessary to add a drive letter in front.

Note: I had to provide the full path to the font file (e.g. /usr/share/fonts/ttf/droid/DroidSansFallbackFull.ttf)

Comment: I can see that you are providing some interesting additional insight (though this is outside of my usual competence). However, your phrasing makes it easily mistaken for a "Me too." or a question of yours. That might (erroneously and undeservedly) get you into some kind of trouble or other. I recommend to rephrase this and stress the part where you explain something to solve a problem observed in comments. Maybe something beginning like "I want to add a solution for a problem described in comments above." I think that should set you up for being recognised as an earnest contributor.

Comment: Well done. However, "answer 1" is ambiguous, note that users can have the answers sorted differently, by age, by votes and by activity. There is hence no clear numering. Use the answerers name and maybe a short summary. Even "oldest" (in case you meant that) is not reliable, because answers can be deleted and undeleted.

Comment: Please understand that I cannot upvote, because I do not know anything about the actual technical matter

Comment: Please read the question carefully .. he wants to load font from Qt Resource system .. which provides access to files through the prefix "_:/_" ..  what you stated is just incorrect :  _The reason is, that there is a leading ':'_

Answer (score 1):

No, see, I didn't do any of this. So for me, what I did was there's a `~/.font/` directory, if it doesn't exist you can create it.

Now you copy the ttf into this directory, and Linux will see it. However, in my case, I'm writing a QT application, so these fonts have names, so how does Linux know the name?

If you run the command:

```
fc-list
```

It dumps out all the font information systemwide and you can search for the font that you've added.

The output looks something like this:

```
...
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans17-oblique.otf: Latin Modern Sans,LM Sans 17:style=17 Oblique,Italic
/home/XXX/.fonts/PAPYRUS.TTF: Papyrus:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/n019064l.pfb: Nimbus Sans L:style=Bold Condensed Italic
...
```

The parts of the output after the first colon on each line is the name of the font as it's seen from inside of Linux for that user. So these are "Latin Modern Sans,LM Sans 17" / "Papyrus" / "Nimbus Sans L". So Linux sees it, and all your applications running as your user will see them also, (Gimp, your Window Manager, QT applications etc etc etc)

Inside your QT application you call the one you are interested in, in my case i'm interested in Papyrus font:

```
tabWidget->setFont( QFont( "Papyrus",10 ) );
```

And then, sure enough the QT application just picks up the font...

If you wanted to make the font systemwide, then you'd have to locate the position of the font directories, from what i can see it's `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/` you will need to create a subdirectory in there for your fonts but perhaps some other distros may be in a different location, you might want to double check that. Anyhow you can dump the ttf files in there. If you do that, you might want to consider running `fc-cache -fv` as this will treewalk through the truetype subdirectories seeking out newly added fonts.

With anything font related under Linux, run `fc-list`. It clears up all sorts of confusions and missunderstandings and sheds light on the otherwise dark and mysterious world of Linux fonts.

Comment: My solution with addApplicationFont was not necessary if I copied (or linked) the font into a directory which was recognised. In my case, the font was not found in /usr/share/fonts but in /usr/lib/fonts.